# Python one pivot table for different type of aggregation

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I have an input df like:

| category | name | cost | cost2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Tier1 | Tina | 10 | 5 |
| Tier1 | Jessy | 20 | 15 |
| Tier1 | Tina | 30 | 10 |

Need output:

| category | count distinct name | sum of cost | avg of cost2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Tier1 | 2 | 60 | 10 |

It is similar to SQL: select category, count(distinct name), sum(cost), avg(cost2) group by category.
I am looking for the equivalent easy way to do it in python, preferably in one statement, if not two. My actual use case has 30 columns so need a way I can simply parse the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```py
x = df.groupby("category", as_index=False).agg(
    count_distinct_name=("name", "nunique"),
    sum_of_cost=("cost", "sum"),
    avg_of_cost2=("cost2", "mean"),
)
x.columns = x.columns.str.replace("_", " ")
print(x)
```

Prints:

```
  category  count distinct name  sum of cost  avg of cost2
0    Tier1                    2           60          10.0
```

Comment: Oh you beat me. You can use parameter expansion to handle the space (see my deleted answer)